# Determinant Matrix NxN from csv file

Tags: c, recursion, matrix, determinants

I am trying to do matrix x determinant operation from csv file, but the result i get is not correct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int p,q; // original matrix dimensions
int det(int B[p][q]);
char buffer [200];
char *record, *line;
int mat[100][100];

int main() {
int determinant;
register int row,column;
FILE *fp = fopen("", "r"); 
if (fp==NULL) 
{
    printf("the file cannot be opened!");
}

row=0;
while ((line=fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) != NULL)
{
    column=0;
    record = strtok(line, ";");  
    while (record!=NULL)
    {
        mat[row][column] = atoi(record);
        record = strtok(NULL, ";"); 
        column++; 
    } 
    row++; 
} 


p=column-1;
q=row;

printf("Matriks from File CSV: \n");
for ( row = 0; row < q; row++)
{
    for ( column = 0; column < p+1; column++)
    {
        printf("%3d\t", mat[row][column]); 
    }
    printf("\n");
}

determinant = det(mat);

printf("determinant = %d \n",determinant);

return 0;
}

int det(int B[q][p]) {
int row_size = q;
    int column_size = p;

if (row_size != column_size) {
    printf("DimensionError: Operation Not Permitted \n");
    exit(1);
}

else if (row_size == 1)
    return (B[0][0]);

else if (row_size == 2)
    return (B[0][0]*B[1][1] - B[1][0]*B[0][1]);

else {
    int minor[row_size-1][column_size-1];
    int row_minor, column_minor;
    int firstrow_columnindex;
    int sum = 0;

    register int row,column;

    // exclude first row and current column
    for(firstrow_columnindex = 0; firstrow_columnindex < row_size;
            firstrow_columnindex++) {

        row_minor = 0;

        for(row = 1; row < row_size; row++) {

            column_minor = 0;

            for(column = 0; column < column_size+1; column++) {
                if (column == firstrow_columnindex)
                    continue;
                else
                    minor[row_minor][column_minor] = B[row][column];

                column_minor++;
            }

            row_minor++;
        }

        q = row_minor;
        p = column_minor;

        if (firstrow_columnindex % 2 == 0)
            sum += B[0][firstrow_columnindex] * det(minor);
    
        else
            sum -= B[0][firstrow_columnindex] * det(minor);

         

    }
    return sum;

}
}
```

But the Result of my Code is:

```
Matriks from File CSV:
1       2       5
6       5       5

determinant = -10
```

That should be "determinant = -7", but I get determinant = -10,  I tried to search but haven't found it.
is there someone who can explain to me where is my mistake? Thanks before.

Comment: Hmmm ... isn't it supposed to be a square matrix?

Comment: Your problem is the declaration of the matrix in `det`: You use the global variables `q` and `p` as dimensions, but your matrix `mat` in main is a 100×100 matrix, even if you use only the upper left 2×2 submatrix. If you change the function signature to `int det(int B[100][100])`, you get the correct determinant. (I'm not so sure that storing the right-hand side vector in the same matrix is a good approach and if you want to solve an equation system, your matrices should probably have floating-point values.)

Comment: thankyou it's working when the ordo matrix is 2x2 but when it is more than 2x2, it comes up with zero result:(

Comment: Well, in the case where the matrix is bigger than 2×2, you enter the full recursive calculation, so try to debug that. I can imagine that there is something wrong when you try to change the size of the matrix via the global variables `p` and `q`; better pass the size in as parameter. (You could always implement Sarrus's rule for a 3×3 matrix, however.)

Answer (score 0):

Wrong access to matrix

```
    else if (row_size == 2) {
        printf("%d * %d - %d * %d\n", B[0][0], B[1][1], B[1][0], B[0][1]);
        return (B[0][0]*B[1][1] - B[1][0]*B[0][1]);
    }
    else {
```

Comment: No difference..?

Comment: Just added the print for you to see for yourself. I'm not going to debug the code any further, sorry.